# ByVal/ByRef to copy data [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, byref, byval

**[Answer found -**
Problem wasn't with the Sourcerange. Apparently it's because I didn't indicate ".xlsx" within Extractdata1 for each of the inputWBs. Somehow, that led to the code churning out the same value for each output cell. After adding .xlsx for each inputWBs, i was able to get the different values.]

I have a code here where i'm trying to use ByVal. I can't find a lot of resources to learn ByVal writing for my purpose (copy paste data), so am struggling with it.

Purpose: Extract data from cell H17 of 3 different input WB, and paste into A1, A2, A3 of output WB respectively.

Problem: The following code currently gives me the same value in A1, A2 and A3... and this value is equal to the last-opened input WB (instead of 3 values from the 3 different input WB).

I have also tried ByRef but it did not fix the problem.

Thank you in advance.

```
Sub Extractdata()
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim FromSheetName As String
    Dim TargetRange As Range

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\[OutputWB].xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Extractdata1 "C:\Users\[InputWB1]", "[InputSheet]", .Range("A1")
        Extractdata1 "C:\Users\[InputWB2]", "[InputSheet]", .Range("A2")
        Extractdata1 "C:\Users\[InputWB3]", "[InputSheet]", .Range("A3")
    End With
End Sub


Sub Extractdata1(ByVal FromPath As String, ByVal FromSheetName As String, ByVal TargetRange As Range)
    With Workbooks.Open(FromPath)
        With .Worksheets(FromSheetName)
            Set SourceRange = .Range("H17")
            TargetRange.Value = SourceRange.Value    
        End With    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Yes, i have tried that as well. It still gives me the figure belonging to the last-opened workbook.

Comment: Where is SourceRange declared?  I suspect it is Module level. This would mean that every time Extractdata1 is called the same variable is set to a new value.  Because your target ranges are assigned the value of this variable, they all get the new value as well.   Try using a local variable (local to Extractdata1) instead.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanWillcock, i have also tried removing sourcerange entirely. i.e. using "TargetRange.Value = .Range("H17")" instead of the 2 lines in the code above . It produced the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Same Cell From Different Files

- This is works on my end. Maybe you can spot a relevant difference.
- `ScreenUpdating` has nothing to do with it, and it also worked when the source files were not being closed.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Extractdata()

    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & "Output.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Extractdata1 FolderPath & "Test1.xlsx", "Sheet1", .Range("A1")
        Extractdata1 FolderPath & "Test2.xlsx", "Sheet1", .Range("A2")
        Extractdata1 FolderPath & "Test3.xlsx", "Sheet1", .Range("A3")
        '.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub Extractdata1( _
        ByVal FromPath As String, _
        ByVal FromSheetName As String, _
        ByVal TargetRange As Range)
    
    With Workbooks.Open(FromPath)
        With .Worksheets(FromSheetName)
            TargetRange.Value = .Range("H17").Value
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow super duper!!! Thanks so much for this, am very grateful! From your answer, i figured out that the reason why my code wasn't working because I didn't indicate ".xlsx" in Extractdata1.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is the link the value of a cell to the value in another workbook there is a simpler way to do it: paste the following formulas into Cells A1, A2 & A3 of OutputWB.xlsm and the job will be done without code.

```
='C:\Users\[InputWB1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H$17
='C:\Users\[InputWB2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H$17
='C:\Users\[InputWB3.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H$17
```

If that doesn't meet your need please see the following revised code. I've removed the square brackets which were causing file not found errors. I've also put the file path into a variable to make it easier to test in a different environment.
I would strongly advise adding a close file instruction at the end unless you want to keep all the workbooks open at the end.

```
Sub Extractdata()

Dim FromPath As String
Dim FromSheetName As String
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = "C:\Users\"

With Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "OutputWB.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

Extractdata1 FilePath & "InputWB1", "InputSheet", .Range("A1")
Extractdata1 FilePath & "InputWB2", "InputSheet", .Range("A2")
Extractdata1 FilePath & "InputWB3", "InputSheet", .Range("A3")

End With

End Sub


Sub Extractdata1(ByVal FromPath As String, ByVal FromSheetName As String, ByVal TargetRange As Range)
    With Workbooks.Open(FromPath)
        With .Worksheets(FromSheetName)
Debug.Print (FromPath)
Set SourceRange = .Range("H17")
TargetRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
    
        End With
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks much for your prompt response. Sorry, i copied the code wrongly, i have updated. Even when i used A1, A2, A3, the issue remains. Would you have any idea what else could be wrong? Thank you~

Comment: Check that H17 is different in the 3 source files.

Comment: Yes, H17 is different in the 3 source files